# View unmodified bytes of a filename on APFS

Tags: itunes, apfs, music.app, unicode

How do I view the bytes of a filename as it’s stored an APFS volume (i.e. without going through Unicode normalization)?

Context: I migrated an old iTunes library to a new Music.app library, and ran the "Consolidate files" operation on the result to tidy things up. Then I used [`rsync`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308319) and [`diff`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314570) to compare the two on disk and got results like:

```
% diff -rq iTunes/iTunes\ Music Music/Media.localized/Music
...
Only in Music/Media.localized/Music: Múm
Only in iTunes/iTunes Music: Múm
```

This led me down the path of learning about [Unicode normalization](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) (explainers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7934397) and [here](https://eclecticlight.co/2021/05/08/explainer-unicode-normalization-and-apfs/)). Those two strings have the same visual representation but are stored differently on disk. This comes up frequently with accented characters.

The question that arose was: How do I quickly get the on-disk byte representation of each name, so that I can be confident I understand what is going on?

BTW, for the original problem of comparing directories, I found this [handy Python script](https://gist.github.com/amakukha/f489cbde2afd32817f8e866cf4abe779) (via [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676425)) which will consider Unicode-equivalent names as matching.

Answer (score 1):

There has got to be a better way, but answering my own question as I at least found *a* way. Just copy the filename from Finder and paste it into your favorite hex dump tool.

```
% xxd
Múm
00000000: 4dc3 ba6d 0a                             M..m.
% xxd
Múm
00000000: 4d75 cc81 6d0a                           Mu..m.
```

Be careful though: If you accidentally get into Finder's rename box, it will overwrite the on-disk byte representation with a normalized form, leaving you very confused.

I lost a lot of time thinking that `ls` would print filenames as they are on disk, and I could pipe that to `xxd` or `od`, but as far as I can tell it actually normalizes before printing.

```
% ls -d Music/Media.localized/Music/M?m | tail -c 5 | xxd
00000000: 4dc3 ba6d 0a                             M..m.
% ls -d iTunes/iTunes\ Music/M?m | tail -c 5 | xxd
00000000: 4dc3 ba6d 0a                             M..m.
```

For a pure-CLI option, there's surely something more direct, but I did find [this Perl script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351886) would do the job.

Comment: The piping doesn't work because your shell expands the glob `?` to single normalised characters, so whilst `?` will match either/both UTF-8 encodings, `c3 ba` and `75 cc 81`, it will always expand to the normalised one, `c3 ba`. The output of `ls` will then include that encoding rather than the 3-byte one, since `ls` always prints the particular input it received. You can see this behaviour of `ls` by providing the other byte string explicitly: `ls "$(echo '4d 75cc81 6d' | xxd -r -p)"` also matches the file, but piping that to `xxd` reveals that `ls` printed the 3-byte encoding instead.

Comment: Wow! Good start. Does `mdls` provide any useful information? If so, I might be able to help with the search / limitation syntax if you want to use that tool

Comment: @bmike Not that I can see. That util is new to me, but I tried `mdls -name kMDItemFSName -raw . | xxd` from within both dirs, and got the same output.